# validate two data columns from difrnt source dataframes in databricks, if data matched(record counts) row wise , then excute the command or else error

Tags: sql, scala, databricks

dataframe -1:

```
created year, rec_counts
2016               50
2015               40
```

Dataframe -2:

```
created year, rec_counts
2016               1000
2015               47
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods you can try.

1. Let's assume the names of two DataFrames are `df1` and `df2`.

   Now, if you just want to count the number of rows and check if both has same row count or not, use `df1.count()` and `df2.count()` and check if both gives the same output (total number of rows in each group).
2. Secondly, you can write statement `df2.except(df1)` and this will return the complete rows which haven't present in other dataframe. If it returns `NULL`, it means both dataframes are same.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and answering the question,  Here I want to assert both the year and record counts should match, coming from two different sources. This is a pipeline in Azure data factory where we are using Databricks notebook to assert this commands. Can we just stop the command line like, end the commands there after, if year and records count doesn;t match. can you help me with python logic or sql code anything is okay.  Thank you